# Is ANOVA good for non-normally distributed series?

Tags: time-series, anova

I just read [Finding Seasonal Spreads](http://quanttrader.info/public/findingSeasonalSpreads.html), by Paul Teetor.
As far as I understand how ANOVA works, it should be accurate for NORMAL distributed series. Financial series are *not* normally distributed, or maybe am I wrong?

Could someone explain why he used ANOVA in this case?

Comment: If your sample sizes are large enough, the CLT will alleviate the need for normality of your variables themselves: it is really only the means of samples that need to be distributed normally.

Comment: @NickSabbe what do you mean with CLT? large sample size means that sereis are normally distributed? could you exmplain this point? thanks....

Comment: [CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem): large sample sizes make the means normally distributed.

Comment: @NickSabbe wait, I have a doubt, using ANOVA i have to subdivide the series in groups, so those groups doesnt have a very large size. what do you think about it?

Comment: Yes, you do need normality of the means _per group_. Note that one typically accepts sample sizes of 30 as "large" enough for CLT (though opinions differ).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1750/discussion-between-dail-and-nick-sabbe)

Comment: @NickSabbe one question about it... if i have a series with 800 numbers and i create 4 groups with 200 numbers each. Does it mean that i could "assume" are normal distributed because 200 > 30 (where 30 is a number that we can take to consider a serie, large or not) Right?

Answer (score 2):

He used ANOVA as "one way to identify seasonal spreads using legitimate statistical techniques." 
However, you must consider the limitation of the analysis (See limitation on http://quanttrader.info/public/findingSeasonalSpreads.html). 
As is known, ANOVA is robust enough to deal with non normal data on large sample sizes (CLT). Nevertheless, ANOVA will give analysts information about the difference on the "levels" of the curves if the data have a seasonal behavior. Then, there are other tools that give analysts more information than ANOVA in such cases: ARIMA models, bootstraping, and so on.

Comment: Should Fligner.test be better then ANOVA in testing difference of variance?

Comment: Could you give me an example using ARIMA model (with R if you know) to check if the variance is constant?

Comment: @Dail ANOVA doesn't test, despite its name, difference of variances. It tests for differences of means of groups. Fligner-Kileen will test for differences of variances of the groups.